# Ongoing case milestone not behaving as expected

Tags: administration, entitlements

*I'll start off by saying that Entitlement Processes are not my strong suite, so I'm sure I'm just doing something dumb or wrong, but I can't figure it out, and neither can some of the other people I've asked about this.*

---

## Background

### Milestones

**First Response:** This milestone is for when the number of public comments equals 0, and after the first public comment is added it should be marked as completed.

**Ongoing response:** This milestone is an ongoing milestone who's start time should be reset whenever the case moves to a status of "Waiting on Tech" or a new Comment is added to the case.

### Fields

**Severity:** Pretty straight forward picklist of 1-4

**Public Comment Count:** A roll-up summary of the number of public comments on the case

**Status:** A picklist containing the public status of the case, "Waiting on Tech", "Waiting on Customer", "Closed"

**Kick Count:** The number of times the case has been "kicked" to update it's milestone.

---

## Current Implementation

Currently, we have the following entitlement process rules. There are rules for each severity level, and all that changes are the Mintues to Complete *(I've condensed them down for ease of reading)*

- **First milestone**

  - **Name:** First Response
  - **Criteria:** (Case: Public Comments EQUALS 0) AND (Case: Severity EQUALS 1)
  - **Minutes to Complete:** 60
  - **Start Time:** Entitlement Process
- **Second milestone**

  - **Name:** Ongoing Response
  - **Criteria:** (Case: Status EQUALS Waiting on Tech) AND (Case: Public Comments GREATER THEN 0) AND (Case: Severity EQUALS 1)
  - **Minutes to Complete:** 60
  - **Start Time:** Milestone Criteria

This works as expected and every time a new public comment is added to the case, the milestone start time is reset to NOW.

---

## New Behavior

There are times where we need to reset (AKA Kick) the milestone on the case to move it forward without making a public comment on the case, or changing the Case's status/severity.  To do this, I changed the entitlement process to the following:

- **First milestone**

  - **Name:** First Response
  - **Criteria:** (Case: Public Comments EQUALS 0) AND (Case: Severity EQUALS 1)
  - **Minutes to Complete:** 60
  - **Start Time:** Entitlement Process
- **Second milestone**

  - **Name:** Ongoing Response
  - **Criteria:** ((Case: Status EQUALS Waiting on Tech) AND (Case: Public Comments GREATER THEN 0) AND (Case: Severity EQUALS 1)) OR ((Case: Status EQUALS Waiting on Tech) AND (Case: Kick Count GREATER THEN 0) AND (Case: Severity EQUALS 1))
  - **Minutes to Complete:** 60
  - **Start Time:** Milestone Criteria

When using this entitlement process, public comments still move the Ongoing Response milestone forward, but it does not move it forward when updating the Case record and incrementing the Kick Count field.

*UPDATE: When making making the criteria only have status, severity and Kick Count the milestone only appears once and does not reset as the count is incremented.  Could the original work as some function of the roll up summary?*

Comment: This is totally outside my area of knowledge, but the one thing that jumps out at me to ask is this: Is there a possible conflict between Minutes to Complete = 60 and your criteria since the Minutes get reset? Could that somehow be preventing your "kick" from activating? Also, if you're going to "kick" it, from what you said, does the value of the case severity even matter? I do understand where it still needs to be waiting on a tech though. Just some thoughts... Good luck! :)

Comment: The severity matters since the amount of time until the target date of the milestone changes from severity to severity.  IE a severity 1 case has 60min, a severity 2 case has 180min, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Patrick. As I said, TOTALLY outside my area.;) BTW, are you only allowing a manual "kick" on severity 1 cases? I learn so much here! Hope someone can provide you with an answer.:)

Comment: No, we're adding the "kick" to all severities, I just didn't want to add all four and have it confuse the issue.  The only difference is the time and the severity level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the only way to do what we are trying to do is via a trigger.  Whenever the criteria happens, you have to go through the CaseMiletones and set the StartDate to now().